# Angular2 passing value to backend in one array

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-services

I have a posts component and in that post component I am fetching users id and commentor's id those who comment on the posts from post microservice and showing that in posts index page. I have a post microservice and user microservice. Now I want to send the ids of user's and commentor's to users microservice and want to fetch the name of them and display that in posts index page.

In posts index page it is showing like this:

```
 Posts user commentor
  A     1      3
  B     6      5
  C     9      4
```

So, in place of 1 3 6 5 9 4 I want to display the name of them and user_id and commentor_id is in one table in user_microservice. In index.html I am displaying the id's like this

```
 <tr *ngFor="let post of posts" >
   <td>{{ post.name }}</td>
   <td>{{ post.user_id }}</td> 
   <td>{{ post.commentor_id }}</td>
 </tr>
```

Could anyone please help me? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post your user microservice too

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you need something that loads i.e. the user display name from the microservice. 
For that case you should create a small component that can do that.

The code then might look like that:

```
<td><app-user-name [userid]="post.user_id"></app-user-name></td>
```

In the component app-user-name you need an input parameter

@Input() userid: string = ''

In the ngOnInit() you then should pick up that value and call the service and load the user display name.
Similar to that:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.someservice.getUserName(this.userid)
    .subscribe(data => this.username = data)
    ....

}
```

In the template of that component you just need to display the {{username}}
The username is displayed as soon as it is loaded.